# How do I enable Python command history editing in bash under virtual environments

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I want to use history recall and command line editing in the python shell.

However, for virtual environments this does not work by default. For example using

```
python3 -v venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

and then invoking the python interpreter

```
python
```

does not allow up/down arrow etc command line editing.

How to get the command line interpreter to work?

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer to this question is that the docs say that all environments that support readline should automatically have command line support in the python interpreter.

However, installing readline is legacy and will often fail to install using pip.

To solve this use:

```
source env/bin/activate
pip install gnureadline
```

then invoke the python interpreter. Command history will now work. By default the `~/.python_history` file will store the command line history. Note this also works for the Django shell.